# Using Unity to plot 3d geometry with sin & cos

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm interested in using Unity for more than just games. Things like data visualization, installation work, interfacing with sensors, etc. I came across a book full of formulas for 3d geometric patterns using sin and cos.

Can anyone tell me how I might translate these formulas into actual visible 3d patterns in Unity? I'm primarily interested in C# solutions.

Here's some examples of mostly 2d plots
https://www.desmos.com/math

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw a curve... X,Y,Z components of your curve is coming from the equation you have possibly with sin and cos and then you need to draw a curve by sampling the curve with small increments and connect the samples with lines... This tutorial gives you a good starting point:
http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/

Comment: Great tutorial, thanks for sharing. But not exactly what I am looking for. I don't need to create bezier curves, simply plot x,y,z points

Comment: This is more like it, Since you pointed me in the right direction will accept your answer.  http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/graphs/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing the other tutorial too.